# Django atomic select for update not locking table for recursive calls?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, transactions

I have a table which is created and populated in PostgreSQL via the following commands :

```
CREATE TABLE my_lock (
    id integer,
    CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

INSERT INTO my_lock VALUES (1) ;
INSERT INTO my_lock VALUES (2) ;
```

This table is represented by the following Django model

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class MyLock(models.Model):
    class Meta(object):
        db_table = 'my_lock'
```

Next, I have the following methods :

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def acquire_lock():
    with transaction.atomic():
        lock = MyLock.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=1).first()
        yield lock


def first_method():
    print "In first method"
    with acquire_lock():
        print "Lock acquired in first_method()"
        second_method()


def second_method():
    print "In second method"
    first_method()
```

**The `acquire_lock()` method is a Python generator, which runs a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query in a transaction.** This should take a lock on the row with id = 1, and since the transaction does not finish when `yield lock` is called, keep holding that lock.

Thus, if we call `first_method()`, the following output **should** be printed :

```
In first method
Lock acquired in first_method()
In second method
In first method
```

However, **in reality** on calling `first_method()`, the following gets printed :

```
In first method
Lock acquired in first_method()
In second method
In first method
Lock acquired in first_method()
In second method
In first method
Lock acquired in first_method()
In second method
In first method
Lock acquired in first_method()
In second method
```

(this continues till a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`)

I am missing something here. How can this happen? How can a row lock in PostgreSQL be acquired more than once?

EDIT :

If I change the `first_method()` to :

```
def first_method():
    print "In first method"
    with acquire_lock():
        print "Lock acquired in first_method()"
        i = 1
        while True:
            i = i + 1
            i = i - 1
```

and, now call `first_method()` from two different terminals (or shells),
one of them prints the following :

```
In first method
Lock acquired in first_method()
```

The second one prints the following :

```
In first method
```

Thus, the lock works in this case, but does not work recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how locks work. In [Row level locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-ROWS):

> Note that a transaction can hold conflicting locks on the same row, even in different subtransactions;

Your code runs in a single transaction. Locks in Postgres are designed to prevent conflicts with *other* transactions. As such, a single transaction can acquire the same lock multiple times, but other transactions cannot acquire that lock as long as it is held by the current transaction.